# Tried to get values by list keys

Tags: zabbix

Tried to get values by list keys

wrote Zabbix API request

```
zabbix_get= \
    {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "item.get",
        "params": {
            "output": "extend",
            "host": "server01",
            # "host": "server01"
            "search": {
                "key_": 'vfs.fs.size[/data,free]','system.cpu.util.usage'
            },
            "sortfield": "name"
        },
        "auth": authToken.get("result"),
        "id": authToken.get("id")
    }
```

BUT returned null.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `key` as an array:

```
['vfs.fs.size[/data,free]','system.cpu.util.usage']
```

Comment: Additionally, single quotes are not supported by JSON for quoting, doublequotes must be used.

Comment: must else to change search to filter

Comment: zabbix_get= \
        {
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "method": "item.get",
            "params": {
                "output": "extend",
                "host": 'server01',
                "filter": {
                    "key_": [
                        "vfs.fs.size[/data,free]",
                        "system.cpu.util.usage"
                    ]
                },
                "sortfield": "name"
            },
            "auth": authToken.get("result"),
            "id": authToken.get("id")
        }